# Searching for a phase transition dataset for substances

Tags: databases, phase-diagram

Disclaimer: I'm not a chemist, just a curious engineer.

As per the title, I'm searching for a dataset (or relevant Python library) with phase transition information for different substances. Eg: water, hydrogen, methane, ethylene... I'm looking to plot a phase transition graph for each substance (temperature vs pressure) so that I can compare them in different environments (by moving the bounds for each axis).

I'm currently using [CoolProp](http://coolprop.org/), but this doesn't seem to include information to form the solid/gas and solid/liquid curves.

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way, or maybe I've not looked hard enough, but I would have thought this information would be relatively easy to find.

Comment: That link doesn't work. Apparently they don't have https capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @Martin-マーチン, fixed,  but as you said no https...

Comment: Oh, alright. That works. I wasn't sure you can use links to http sites anymore. Anyway. You're looking for phase diagrams of pure substances. I'd expect the handbook of chemistry and physics to have that. But I cannot check.

Comment: Note you don't have phase transitions for molecules. A phase transition is a property of the whole macroscopic system, not an individual molecule, so it would be better to say something like "substance" rather than molecule. And an upvote for the avoidance of non-https sites

Comment: Thanks @IanBush, edited accordingly.